# Need help for solving Switch Case Statement for rock-paper-scissors

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code for Rock switch-statement doesn't work sometimes, it gets logged but doesn't run.
This is my **first time building a project**, pls help

````
function getComputerChoices() {
  const choice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return choice[randomNumber];
}

//Game logic function
function game(userChoice) {
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoices();
  console.log(`user choice => ${userChoice}`);
  console.log(`user choice => ${computerChoice}`);
  switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
    case "rockscissors":
    case "paperrock":
    case "scissorspaper":
      console.log(`User Win's.`);
      userScore_span.innerText++;
      break;

    case "rockspaper":
    case "paperscissors":
    case "scissorsrock":
      console.log(`User looses.`);
      computerScore_span.innerText++;
      break;

    case "rocksrock":
    case "paperpaper":
    case "scissorsscissors":
      console.log(`Its a Tie`);
      break;
  }
}```
````

Comment: Typo: `rocksrock`, `rockspaper`,

Comment: No that is for tie statement like ```rock&paper,rock&scissors,rock&rock``` 
where rock is user-selector and paper is computer-selector

Comment: You have an extra `s` there. The choices are `["rock", "paper", "scissors"]`. So you can have `rockrock` but not `rocksrock`.

Comment: Thanks, man, it was a great help.
I face issues coz my code spell checker did not show a warning/error while logging, I was checking the code for the past 3hrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getComputerChoices() {
  const choice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return choice[randomNumber];
}

//Game logic function
function game(userChoice) {
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoices();
  console.log(`user choice => ${userChoice}`);
  console.log(`computer choice => ${computerChoice}`);
  switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
    case "rockscissors":
    case "paperrock":
    case "scissorspaper":
      //console.log(`User Win's.`);
      var span = document.getElementById('s').innerText = 'user Wins!'
     // userScore_span.innerText++;
      break;

    case "rockpaper":
    case "paperscissors":
    case "scissorsrock":
     // console.log(`User looses.`);
     // computerScore_span.innerText++;
      var span = document.getElementById('s').innerText = 'user loses!'
      break;

    case "rockrock":
    case "paperpaper":
    case "scissorsscissors":
     // console.log(`Its a Tie`);
      var span = document.getElementById('s').innerText = 'It\'s a tie!'
      break;
  }
}

game('rock')
```

```html
<span id ='s'></span>
```